# Get passed data on next page after calling "to" from NavContainer

Tags: sapui5

I am on my way building a Fiori like app using SAPUI5. I have successfully built the *Master* page, and on item click, I pass the context and navigate to *Detail* page.

The context path from Master page is something like `/SUPPLIER("NAME")`. The function in `App.controoler.js` is as follows:

```js
handleListItemPress: function(evt) {
  var context = evt.getSource().getBindingContext();
  this.myNavContainer.to("Detail", context);
  // ...
},
```

But I would like to know how I can access this `context` in the *Detail* page. I need this because I need to use `$expand` to build the URL and bind the items to a table.

Answer (score 1):

There is an example in the [UI5 Documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/cddf7e54277446a4a35c9fd9285da009) on how to deal with this problem using an `EventDelegate` for the `onBeforeShow` function which is called by the framework automatically. I adapted it to your use case:

```js
this.myNavContainer.to("Detail", context); // trigger navigation and hand over a data object
```

```js
// and where the detail page is implemented:
myDetailPage.addEventDelegate({
  onBeforeShow: function(evt) {
    var context = evt.data.context;
  }
});
```

The `evt.data` object contains all data you put in `to(<pageId>, <data>)`. You could log it to the console to see the structure of the `evt` object.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer the "shopping cart" example in SAP UI5 Demo Kit.

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/cart/index.html?responderOn=true

Generally, in 'Component.js', the routes shall be configured for the different views.

And in the views, the route has to be listened to. Please see below.

In Component.js:

```
routes: [
      { pattern: "cart",
        name: "cart",
    view: "Cart",
    targetAggregation: "masterPages"
      }
        ]
```

And in Cart.controller.js, the route has to be listened. In this example, cart is a detail

```
    onInit : function () {
         this._router = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
         this._router.attachRoutePatternMatched(this._routePatternMatched, this);
   },

    _routePatternMatched : function(oEvent) {
    if (oEvent.getParameter("name") === "cart") {
        //set selection of list back
        var oEntryList = this.getView().byId("entryList");
        oEntryList.removeSelections();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Using the Router is the recommended approach but it's not solving the question.